# A Poker Problem to verify

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

How to find the number of ways that two pairs of card and one card be chosen to choose a total of five cards from a standard deck of 52 cards? Ex: AA228, KKJJ3, 77885 are some examples of such choosing. Please provide the logic and not just the solution for this. And also, even though it's impossible to verify this by making a large list and counting them, but, how do we verify that the answer is correct?

Comment: It's not impossible to verify it by making a large list and counting them. There are only 52C5 or 2,598,960 hands of five cards. This is easily checked by making a list on a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really very difficult, and the proof is basically that the [rules of combinations and choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) are well understood.

To choose the two ranks of the pairs, you have $\binom {13}2$ options. This is a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) representing the number of ways $2$ items can be chosen from a pool of $13$, often said "$13$ choose $2$". The actual number is calculated as:
$$\binom {13}2 = \frac{13!}{(13-2)!2!} = \frac{13\cdot 12}{2\cdot 1} = 78$$

Then to chose the suits for each pair, you have $\binom {4}2 = 6$ options each. Finally to choose the remaining card there are $11$ remaining ranks and $4$ suits in each so there are $44$ options.

Multiply these together to reflect that the choices are independent:
$$\binom {13}2\binom {4}2\binom {4}2\binom {44}1 = 78\cdot 6\cdot 6\cdot 44 = 123552 $$

Comment: why do we only consider one suit of cards? Aren't there 4.13C2(i.e 4 times 13 choose 2) ways for two cards to be chosen?

Comment: We do consider all suits of cards, but first, to get the pairs, we consider only rank. Then the $\binom 42$ gives us the chosen suits for each pair.